# I can’t get show to work correctly

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have four graphs to show together. I’ve named them first, second, third, and fourth. When I use Show[first, second, third, fourth] it only gives the graph of the first one. When I use GraphicsRow[first, second, third, fourth] it gives all four separately so I don’t think it’s a problem with the graphs?

Comment: try `Show[first, second, third, fourth, PlotRange -> All]`?

Comment: Yes!!!! Thank you so much!!!!!!!